# JQuery Cookie plugin - check for presence of cookie

Tags: jquery-plugins

I hope this is a simple question, but can't find it covered elsewhere.

I simply want check for the presence of a cookie - if it's there, do nothing, but if it's not there, replace the content of a particular div (I think I know how to do this last bit.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check cookie existence at server side before rendering page.  you will get all cookie details in request object 
If your cookie  not there,then replace the content of a particular div in server side 
otherwise you can check in client side as below,
 `if (jQuery.cookie('cookietitle')) {
          // Reactions
     }`

Comment: Sorry I meant to explain that this was the code I've currently got - not working though. (I'm very much new to this, as you can see ...

$(document).ready(function() {
var moodle_cookie = $.cookie("MoodleSession");
if (moodle_cookie = null) 
$("div#cycle-content").each (function(){
$(this).replaceWith("<div id='cycle-content'><p><strong>Access to this content requires a valid University of Nottingham Moodle login</strong><p></div>");
});
});

Answer (score 0):

You may read it like var cookieValue = $.cookie("test"); And check the cookieValue if is empty.

Check this answer for more details how to work with cookies:
[How do I set/unset cookie with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery)